# A sci fi story about a man who becomes a machine then a ship then a god

Tags: story-identification

I read this book a couple decades ago, and I can't remember the title or the author.

It was a story about an interstellar war, and about this guy who was special because of his reaction speed and his ability to pilot the ships to fight in the war. He was so valuable that they used his sperm to try and create more pilots like him.
Over the years though he became more and more machine as they replaced his body parts. Till eventually he is integrated into the ship, if memory serves.

Then ... for some reason he goes searching and I think finds some higher beings, a kind o council of super aliens and eventually becomes a sort of demi god or a member of the council.

There was some interplay with a female pilot through the book as well, I think she was used as one of the potential mothers of his children to try and recreate his specialness. This failed I think, but ... for some reason ... she became a sort of counter balance to him in the story. Its mainly to get this sorted out in my head that I want to reread the book.

I was a fan of classic sci-fi at the time so I think it may have been from the 60s or so.

If anyone could point me in the right direction it would be a great help, I can't get this book out of my head and I'd really like to read it again.

The story was spread out over very long periods of time if memory serves, I can't remember if it was due to time dilation or machine augmented life spans or both, I think it was both.

PS:For Context at the time I was reading about a book a day,I read thousands over a 6 year period,which is why the author names and titles are a bit blurry sometimes.I only really remember authors If I read 10+ of their books.

Comment: It sounds like you're horribly misremembering "[The Days of Solomon Gursky](http://tinyurl.com/jogd2bz).

Comment: No that is much too late, I read the book before that book was published.

Comment: If anything it is closer to The Forever Man by Gordon R Dickson. But that isn't it.

Comment: Seems similar to a chapter/prologue/epilogue of 2001:A Space Odyssey, referring to the race that placed the obelisk thing on the moon and on Europa/Titan (the detail was changed in the film).

Comment: No, the guy in question was human. I'm pretty sure of that.

Comment: The closest I can get to this is 'The Ship who..' series by Anne McCaffrey. The protagonist was female and the series was written from 1961 to 1969. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Ship_Who_Sang

Comment: Just thought of another alternative, but from much latter, 'the Culture Ships' in the Books by Ian M. Banks. However they are controlled by AI's. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_spacecraft_in_the_Culture_series

Comment: Yhea I know Ian Banks, I've read several of the books about the Culture Ships. Not what I was thinking of sadly.

Comment: As for Anne McCaffrey, I know her mainly for the pern series. I wasn't aare of the Ship who sang, I'll have to track down a copy. Story line actually reminds me more of C.J Cherryh.

Comment: This sounds like Fred Saberhagen's novel *[Berserker Man](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/16504.Berserker_Man)* (1979), and the characters [Frank Marcus and Michel Geulincx](http://www.berserkerfan.org/charactersSP.htm).

Comment: Unless you have massively misremembered it's not Ship who Sang.

Comment: @Gaultheria Parts of it sound a bit like Berserker Man, but not the breeding and demigods elements.

Comment: @Buzz I admit I'm using Google to supplement a rusty memory.  I think the OP might be conflating the two Saberhagen characters: Frank the cyborg war hero is recruited into a breeding program that produces Michel, and Michel becomes a kind of "energy cyborg" and joins a council of ascended beings in the Taj.

Comment: @Gaultheria That sounds very plausible.  The title of the question immediately made me think of Berserker Man, but I was thrown by the part about the breeding, since Michel is not even sexually mature when he merges with the ship.

Comment: We are Legion; We are Bob is much too recent too be what you're looking for, but it matches the title pretty well.

Comment: @Gaultheria Thanks for the tip, just ordered berserker man, I'll give it a read and see.

Comment: @Seldon2k I read the Ship who * series. Not what I was looking for, but an ok read.

Comment: @Charles_F Also ordered We are legion; we are bob. I'll give it a read as well.

Comment: Its very possible I'm muddling some of the parts. 
Thanks to everyone for the suggestions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This could be Fred Saberhagen's novel *[Berserker Man](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/16504.Berserker_Man)* (1979).

Frank Marcus, a cyborg war hero, is recruited into a breeding program that produces Michel Geulincx.  Michel becomes a kind of "energy cyborg" and joins a council of ascended beings.

Character descriptions: [The Taj: Official Fan Site of Fred Saberhagen's Berserker Universe](http://www.berserkerfan.org/charactersSP.htm).

Comment: Thanks, only on the first couple of chapters, but this is I think the book(s) I was looking for.